# How come my background is transparent?

Tags: css

I have 2 divs withing a container div. I set the background color of the container to white and did not set colors for the 2 other divs. Was expecting to see a white background thanks to the color of the container but everything is transparent. Is it normal? Looks like the container's color is not taken into consideration. Tks http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/svt2s/

CSS

```
#team-container
{
    width:960px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=83)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=83);
    opacity: 0.83; /* For IE8 and earlier */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #fff;
}

#team-left {
color:#000;
padding-left:20px;
padding-top:20px;
/* padding:15px;*/
width: 30%; 
float: left;
position: relative; 
}

#team-right { 
font:12px 'Open Sans', "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
padding-left:25px;
padding-top:28px;
color:#000;
width: 60%; 
float: left;
position: relative; 
text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: Here's a tip: (isn't completely necessary, but it helps people answer your question faster), if you paste your HTML and CSS in the respective places on http://jsfiddle.net, you can show us a live, editable, demo of what you were explaining! It's really useful for HTML/CSS/Javascript snippet questions.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, paste the html here.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/svt2s/

Comment: Be aware that when opacity is set for an element, it will be applied to all content within that element, including any child elements. Sometimes this is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parent element must contain its floated children, or else the parent does not occupy any space in the layout (it will have a height of 0 for layout purposes). This is why you're not seeing the white background of the parent.

You can contain the floated children in one of two ways (both accomplish the same thing):

**clearfix**

```
.clearfix {...}   /* Insert standard clearfix code here */
...
<div id="team-container class="clearfix">
    <div id="team-left"></div>
    <div id="team-right"></div>
</div>
```

**clear div**

```
.clear {clear:both;}
...
<div id="team-container">
    <div id="team-left"></div>
    <div id="team-right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

[Modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svt2s/2/) with a clear div and a light gray background.

[Modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/svt2s/3/) with clearfix and a light gray background.

Answer (score 1):

Background color and opacity are not  inheritable attributes. If you do not define it for any specific element/selector, it will not be set.